# Does destroy result in cascaded delete of the dependents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

Does destroy result in cascaded delete of the dependents across the supported databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as each dependent model has the attribute set in the model definition.